# Angular - write one subscribe method which in "next()" function have different code

Tags: angular, async-await, observable, subscribe

I have user.service.ts where I have method with http request and return an Observable.

```
getUser(userId): Observable<IUser> {
    return this._httpClient.get(_apiParameters.url + '/users/' + userId, httpOptions)
      .pipe(map((res: IUser) => {
        return res;
      })
      );
  }
```

In my user.conponent.ts I have methods method1(), method2(), method3() where I subscribe to userService.getUser(userId)

```
  method1() {
    this.userService.getUser(userId).subscribe(res => {
      this.user = res;
    })
  }
  method2() {
    this.userService.getUser(userId).subscribe(res => {
      this.user = res;
    })
    showCredit();
  }
  method3() {
    this.userService.getUser(userId).subscribe(res => {
      this.user = res;
      addCredit(this.user.id);
    })
  }
```

But in method3() in subscribe I have this.user = res; and addCredit(this.user.id);
I have tried like

```
initializeUser() {
     this.userService.getUser(userId).subscribe(res => {
      this.user = res;
    })
}
```

And then to call initializeUser() in every other method, but in that case I'm losing addCredit(this.user.id); and I need that "id" from response.

How can I write code so I dont repeat that subscribe in every method and to wait for subscribe so I can call addCredit(this.user.id) in method3();

Comment: you can simply add a parameter to the function and conditionally invocate addCredit depending on this parameter.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
initializeUser(shouldAddCredit: boolean) {
     this.userService.getUser(userId).subscribe(res => {
         this.user = res;
         if (shouldAddCredit) {
              addCredit(this.user.id);
         }
    })
}

method1() {
    this.initializeUser(false);
}

method2() {
    this.initializeUser(false);
    showCredit();
}

method3() {
    this.initializeUser(true);
}
```